# How to convert a string or integer to binary in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, binary, encode

How do you create integers 0..9 and math operators + - * / in to  binary strings.
For example:

```
 0 = 0000,
 1 = 0001, 
 ...
 9 = 1001
```

Is there a way to do this with Ruby 1.8.6 without using a library?

Comment: When you say you want to convert math operators to binary strings, what exactly do you mean?  Use the ASCII representation written in binary?

Comment: I guess u wanted to do the popular Genetic Algorithm thing? :-)

Answer (score 431):

You have `Integer#to_s(base)` and `String#to_i(base)` available to you.

`Integer#to_s(base)` converts a decimal number to a string representing the number in the base specified:

```
9.to_s(2) #=> "1001"
```

while the reverse is obtained with `String#to_i(base)`:

```
"1001".to_i(2) #=> 9
```

Comment: @TomRavenscroft In addition, you can use `("%08b" % int)` or `("%08b" % string)` to return a fixed number of bits.

Comment: `-9.to_s(2)`
`=> "-1001"`
Can someone explain this?

Comment: For those confused by @decay's code like myself, he is using 'sprintf': https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/sprintf

Comment: @user1201917 What's wrong with that? `9` is `1001` in binary.

Comment: @preferred_anon Unbelievable, but just 2 hours ago I discussed binary conversions in ruby with my colleague
Last time IRL I discussed binary numbers in ruby about 5 years ago.
And now I check notifications on stackoverflow and see your answer to 3-years-ago comment... about binary numbers in ruby. 
What a coincidence!
Yes, `9` is `1001` but `(-9)` is not `-1001`. `to_i` depends on `NUM2INT` impl. which [was caused an error on negative values](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9089)
[More info](https://silverhammermba.github.io/emberb/c/#methods)

Comment: @user1201917 How remarkable! I must say I very rarely come across negative binary numbers, but at least when I've seen them in maths the notation `-1001` would be correct for `-9`. Is there some notation for a signed bit or something that is more common among programmers?

Comment: @preferred_anon negative numbers usually represented as two's complements. For -9 it will be `(inverse of ...00001001) + 1 -> ...11110111`. It can be "verified" with `-9[i]` method which returns the bit at a `i` position

Answer (score 47):

I asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19853566/how-to-return-a-fixed-length-binary-representation-of-an-integer-in-ruby). Based on [@sawa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19853637/1836143)'s answer, the most succinct way to represent an integer in a string in binary format is to use the string formatter:

```
"%b" % 245
=> "11110101"
```

You can also choose how long the string representation to be, which might be useful if you want to compare fixed-width binary numbers:

```
1.upto(10).each { |n| puts "%04b" % n }
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
0111
1000
1001
1010
```

Comment: I did some local test to convert integers to binary string, but the result shows that codes like `245.to_s(2)` will be faster than `"%b" % 245`

Comment: Also this doesn't work properly with negative values.

Answer (score 23):

Picking up on bta's lookup table idea, you can create the lookup table with a block. Values get generated when they are first accessed and stored for later:

```
>> lookup_table = Hash.new { |h, i| h[i] = i.to_s(2) }
=> {}
>> lookup_table[1]
=> "1"
>> lookup_table[2]
=> "10"
>> lookup_table[20]
=> "10100"
>> lookup_table[200]
=> "11001000"
>> lookup_table
=> {1=>"1", 200=>"11001000", 2=>"10", 20=>"10100"}
```

Answer (score 11):

You would naturally use `Integer#to_s(2)`, `String#to_i(2)` or `"%b"` in a real program, but, if you're interested in how the translation works, this method calculates the binary representation of a given integer using basic operators:

```
def int_to_binary(x)
  p = 0
  two_p = 0
  output = ""

  while two_p * 2 <= x do
    two_p = 2 ** p
    output << ((two_p & x == two_p) ? "1" : "0")
    p += 1
  end

  #Reverse output to match the endianness of %b
  output.reverse
end
```

To check it works:

```
1.upto(1000) do |n|
  built_in, custom = ("%b" % n), int_to_binary(n)
  if built_in != custom
    puts "I expected #{built_in} but got #{custom}!"
    exit 1
  end
  puts custom
end
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're only working with the single digits 0-9, it's likely faster to build a lookup table so you don't have to call the conversion functions every time.

```
lookup_table = Hash.new
(0..9).each {|x|
    lookup_table[x] = x.to_s(2)
    lookup_table[x.to_s] = x.to_s(2)
}
lookup_table[5]
=> "101"
lookup_table["8"]
=> "1000"
```

Indexing into this hash table using either the integer or string representation of a number will yield its binary representation as a string.

If you require the binary strings to be a certain number of digits long (keep leading zeroes), then change `x.to_s(2)` to `sprintf "%04b", x` (where `4` is the minimum number of digits to use).

Comment: @bta- I'm encoding all these characters into binary so I can use them in a genetic algorithm. I really like the idea of a lookup table for the encode/decode since the set is limited to 0..9 and +-*/

Answer (score 4):

In ruby Integer class, to_s is defined to receive non required argument radix called `base`, pass 2 if you want to receive binary representation of a string.

Here is a link for an official documentation of [String#to_s](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Integer.html#method-i-to_s)

```rb
  1.upto(10).each { |n|  puts n.to_s(2) }
```

Comment: This answer would improve significantly if you could edit it and describe how the code solves the problem

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a Ruby class/method I used this, and I have also included the tests:

```
class Binary
  def self.binary_to_decimal(binary)
    binary_array = binary.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i)
    total = 0

    binary_array.each_with_index do |n, i|
      total += 2 ** (binary_array.length-i-1) * n
    end
    total
   end
end

class BinaryTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_1
   test1 = Binary.binary_to_decimal(0001)
   assert_equal 1, test1
  end

 def test_8
    test8 = Binary.binary_to_decimal(1000)
    assert_equal 8, test8
 end

 def test_15
    test15 = Binary.binary_to_decimal(1111)
    assert_equal 15, test15
 end

 def test_12341
    test12341 = Binary.binary_to_decimal(11000000110101)
    assert_equal 12341, test12341
 end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I am almost a decade late but if someone still come here and want to find the code without using inbuilt function like to_S then I might be helpful.

find the binary

```
def find_binary(number)
  binary = []  
  until(number == 0)
    binary << number%2
    number = number/2
  end
  puts binary.reverse.join
end
```