# How to return a fixed length binary representation of an integer in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, binary, integer

I know that I can use `Fixnum#to_s` to represent integers as strings in binary format. However `1.to_s(2)` produces `1` and I want it to produce `00000001`. How can I make all the returned strings have zeros as a fill up to the 8 character? I could use something like:

```
binary = "#{'0' * (8 - (1.to_s(2)).size)}#{1.to_s(2)}" if (1.to_s(2)).size < 8
```

but that doesn't seem very elegant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use string format.

```
"%08b" % 1
# => "00000001"
```

Answer (score 8):

Using [`String#rjust`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-rjust):

```
1.to_s(2).rjust(8, '0')
=> "00000001"
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`String#%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-25) method to format a string

```
 "%08d" % 1.to_s(2)
 # => "00000001"
```

Here is a [reference](http://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet) for different formatting options.

Comment: Great Link and Nice answer(*+1*)