# How do I Improve this code

Tags: ruby

This is the original code.

```
def d_to_b(dec, bin="")
    dec = dec.to_i
    if (dec < 2)
        bin += dec.to_s
        bin = bin.reverse
        return bin
    else
        a = dec%2
        bin += a.to_s
        d_to_b(dec/2, bin)
    end
end

def b_to_d(bin)
    bin = bin.to_s
    a = (bin.length - 1)
    dec = 0
    i = 0
    while(i <= a)
        dec += (bin[i].to_i)*(2**(a-i))
        i += 1
    end
    return dec
end
```

I want to improve the code. make it faster, and shorten it. Any help, perhaps a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: Oh, looks like a duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339695/how-to-convert-a-string-or-integer-to-binary-in-ruby

Comment: If the code works then check out [codereview.se].

Comment: You need to first state the problem you are trying to solve rather than asking the reader to try to figure that out by studying your code. You should read through the SO [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: Can you please add example input  and the expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby has built in methods to do base conversions. [`Fixnum#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Fixnum.html#method-i-to_s) will take a base to convert to, and [`String#to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-to_i) will take a base to convert from.

```
$ ruby -e 'puts 12.to_s(2); puts "1100".to_i(2)'
1100
12
```

Ruby does this work in C, you're not going to do it faster.

If you want to see how Ruby does it, have a look at [`rb_fix2str()`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/94468b4ea5d46eed4280841b7770f650870b52b3/numeric.c#L3166) and [`rb_cstr_parse_inum()`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/94468b4ea5d46eed4280841b7770f650870b52b3/bignum.c#L4005). They're not simple.