# How to bitwise AND two bit strings in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, bitwise-and

The input data I have are bit strings, assumed to be a binary numbers, each 4 bytes:

```
str  = "11111111010011111111111010000001"
str2 = "11000000000000000000000000000011"
```

And I would like to combine the two strings using a bitwise AND, like so

```
str & str2 #=> "11000000000000000000000000000001"
```

I have tried converting both strings to integers using `str.to_i` but Ruby treats the input as base 10, rather than base 2:

```
str.to_i #=> 11111111010011111111111010000001
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2340415/525478

Comment: Hint: `String#to_i` accepts parameter.

Comment: What number does `11111111010011111111111010000001` represent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code should do what you are looking for:

```
str  = "11111111010011111111111010000001"
str2 = "11000000000000000000000000000011"

result = str.to_i(2) & str2.to_i(2)

result.to_s(2)
=> "11000000000000000000000000000001"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `to_i` to convert from binary notation and `to_s` to convert back to it by specifying the base as an argument. 2 is binary, 8 is octal, 16 is hex.

For example a generic solution here:

```
def binary_add(*items)
  items.map { |i| i.to_i(2) }.reduce(:&).to_s(2)
end
```

Where that uses `map` to convert all the items to integers, then combines those together with `&` into a singular value. That value's then converted back to a base-two string.

Which can be called like this:

```
binary_add(
  "11111111010011111111111010000001",
  "11000000000000000000000000000011"
)

# => "11000000000000000000000000000001"
```

Answer (score 2):

Without converting to and from integer:

```
str.gsub('1') { str2[$~.begin(0)] }
#=> "11000000000000000000000000000001"
```

It replaces each `1` in `str` with the corresponding character in `str2`.

[`$~`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Special+global+variables) returns the match and [`begin`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/MatchData.html#method-i-begin) its index.